# Fix the scenario where Git doesn't recognize the Text editor's close event during merging branches

Tags: git, event-handling, sublimetext3, git-merge, text-editor

I have Git for Windows 2.27.0 installed on the Windows 10 64-bit system.

Until now all instances of `git merge` commands were executing just fine. But now when I run the command `git merge --no-ff <BranchID>`, it opens the text editor(I have configured Sublime Text 3 thro' `subl.exe` file, and the path is correct) and shows the message `Merge branch '<BranchID>' into staging`, but when I close that same `MERGE_MSG` file or editor, it gets stuck in the console screen with the below message:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
```

And when I press `Ctrl + C`, it shows the below error additionally:

```
There was a problem with the editor '"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\subl.exe" -w'.
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
```

How do I fix this issue from the root cause, instead of following the fallback instruction `use 'git commit' to complete the merge.`?

Comment: Does modifying the merge comment then saving it before closing do anything?

Comment: Yes, in fact, interestingly when I didn't modify anything in the `MERGE_MSG` file, but just **clicked** once in it and then close the file/editor, it did went thro' without getting stuck, but I need to know why it happens, and how can we get rid of that **click** requirement, and just closed the file without doing anything and still the command goes further, is this possible ?

Comment: I can only guess, but what might be going on is a new view might be created with the text, but the view doesn't get set as the *active* view until it has been interacted with. Only then can the git plugin store the commit message and continue on with its work. Like I said, it's a guess, but plausible. I don't know enough about Sublime's internals to speculate further.

Comment: The editor process that Git spawned needs to exit successfully in order for Git to recognize that editing is complete.  If you are not exiting the editor (i.e., you're just closing the file being edited), then Git has no way of knowing your edit is complete.